# multiple named windows in a postgres query

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

The [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html) specify a window definition clause thus:

```
[ WINDOW window_name AS ( window_definition ) [, ...] ]
```

The **[,...]** specifies that multiple windows are possible. I find nothing else in the docs to confirm or deny it's possible. How do I make this work?

In this query, I can use either window clause on its own but I can't use both even though the syntax follows the spec:

```sql
select q.*
, min(value) over w_id as min_id_val
--, min(value) over w_kind as min_kind_val
from (
    select 1 as id, 1 as kind, 3.0 as value
    union select 1, 2, 1.0
    union select 2, 1, 2.0
    union select 2, 2, 0.5
) as q
window w_id as (partition by id)
-- , 
-- window w_kind as (partition by kind)
```

I can get the technical effect by not using window definitions, but that gets tiresome for a complex query where windows are re-used:

```sql
select q.*
, min(value) over (partition by id) as min_id_val
, min(value) over (partition by kind) as min_kind_val
from (
    select 1 as id, 1 as kind, 3.0 as value
    union select 1, 2, 1.0
    union select 2, 1, 2.0
    union select 2, 2, 0.5
) as q
```

Comment: Some remarks on why the documentation is the way it is are [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKFQuwaGrwFF0Y234%2Bn7wXK0FtWyO5%3DhucD9Qd6MpCrJKiqT7w%40mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 10):

Don't repeat the `window` keyword:

```
select q.*, 
       min(value) over w_id as min_id_val, 
       min(value) over w_kind as min_kind_val
from (
  values 
   (1,1,3.0),
   (1, 2, 1.0),
   (2, 1, 2.0),
   (2, 2, 0.5)
) as q(id,kind,value)
window w_id as (partition by id), 
       w_kind as (partition by kind)
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer. I'd tick this as correct but created a new account for a new project and Stack Overflow won't let me!

Comment: @MichaelGrazebrook https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts